# Facing the "Messaging may be unavailable" error - WhatsApp Cloud API

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I signed up for the WhatsApp Cloud API and received a test number by default. Unfortunately, I am unable to send messages using that number, as it is not sending any OTP to my targeted number at all. Additionally, an error stating "**Messaging may be unavailable**" is displayed. While checking for errors, I couldn't find anything related to it. I'm not sure what's wrong with it. I need some assistance in solving this issue. Thank you.

[image]